# What is the difference between Brep and polygonal mesh in 3D Geometric Representations?

Tags: 3d, mesh, brep

I am confused about Brep (Boundary Representation) and polygonal mesh. Because both of them are a collection of vertices , edges and faces, but in computer graphic books Brep is explained under Solid Modeling section while polygonal mesh is explained under surface modeling. So what is the difference between two representations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BRep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_representation) commonly refers to solid with faces defined as primitive (planar, cylindrical, conical, spherical, toroidal) or [Nurbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) surfaces while for polygonal meshes faces are always planar (most of the times, triangles).